# Test strategy for testing Data Masking?

Tags: manual-testing, test-management, test-design

I am testing data masking of information like credit card no's, bank accounts etc.

***Data masking or data obfuscation is the process of hiding original data with random characters or data.***

What approach/strategy should I use while testing it. The values are not getting masked in Database application.

Example: Credit card no: 5453-4444-5555-7777 will become ****7777... any no of random chars in front of the string?

Comment: The requirement is ambiguous, and the only person who can give you the correct answer is whoever gave you this assignment in the first place.  There are conventions for dealing with credit card numbers, but there is more than one convention, and without more context, no one can tell which which convention is the right one for your needs.

Comment: ok thanks for the insight! I need to think out of the box ideas to find bugs in such kind of feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thought would be to use a regular expression search. For example, if you have a flat file, just grep for a credit card pattern.

Here is a site that gives regex strings for credit cards: http://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html

Good luck.

John